# Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'products.quantity'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'products.quantity'

when I tried this code it gives an error "Uncaught Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'products.quantity'"

```
      import Actions from './actionTypes'
import * as DB from '../../firebase/database'

export function saleAction(storeData){
     console.log('222222222222',storeData)
    return dispatch =>{

        dispatch(SaleAction());
        return DB.database.ref('/sale').push(storeData).then((data)=>{
            return DB.database.ref('/products/').once('value',(snap)=>{
                var oldQty  = parseInt(snap.val().quantity);
                console.log('quantityyyyyyyyyyy',oldQty)
                var newQty  = parseInt(oldQty - parseInt(storeData.quantity));
                return DB.database.ref('/products').set(newQty,(done)=>{
                    alert('successfuly')
                    dispatch( SaleActionSuccess(data))
                })
            })

        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            dispatch((SaleActionFailed(error)))
            alert('failed')
        })


    }
}

export function SaleAction(){
    return{
        type:Actions.ADDSALEREQUEST
    }
}

export function SaleActionSuccess(data){
    return{
        type: Actions.ADDSALEREQUESTSUCCESS,
        data
    }
}
export function SaleActionFailed(){
    return{
        type: Actions.ADDSALEREQUESTFAILED
    }
}
export default saleAction;
```

Comment: what is `snapshot`? I'm guessing its a form input. What is its `val()`? `parseInt` returns `NaN` if it can't parse what you give it

Comment: oh actually `snapshot.val().quantity` looks wrong since `val()` returns a string